# How to use Case statement in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

This is my SQL Query

```
CASE WHEN (1>2) THEN(
    select * from rate limit 10
    )
    ELSE
    (
    select * from rate limit 1
    )
```

When I use Case statement like above , I can get error like below.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 2: CASE WHEN (1>2) THEN(
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 2
```

Can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: A CASE _statement_ can only be used in [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). A CASE _expression_ needs a complete SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `SELECT` in front of the `CASE` statement. Also, you need an `END` after the last statement of the `CASE`. You need a place for the result of the `CASE` expression to be stored. The examples in the documentation are not executing statements that return a value; just variable assignment. So you don't need a `SELECT` there. If you don't care about the return from the overall query, you can use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT`.

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN 1 > 2 -- always false
       THEN (SELECT * FROM rate LIMIT 10)
       ELSE (SELECT * FROM rate LIMIT 1)
        END
;
```

---

You can also assign the result of the subqueries to a variable if this `CASE` is defined inside of a function.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    CASE WHEN 1 > 2
    THEN (SELECT * INTO rec FROM rate LIMIT 10)
    ELSE (SELECT * INTO rec FROM rate LIMIT 1)
     END
    ;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```